# Viridis and felodon: shared worldbuilding?

Tags: names, inspiration

A recent question in the "Hal Clement challenge" asked if there was [any meaning or significance to the name "felodon"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243849/any-meaning-or-significance-to-the-name-felodon), an amphibian carnivore with large fangs that featured in Clement's novella of 1963, [The Green World](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/61509/61509-h/61509-h.htm). Some years earlier in 1956, Margaret St. Clair wrote [The Green Queen](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3352), available at the Internet Archive under a [slightly different name](https://archive.org/details/Universe_10_1955-03/page/n7/mode/2up). It too was set on a green planet (like Clement's world it was called "Viridis" from the Latin word for green), and also involved an unpleasant fanged predator called a felodon.

Given these similarities, I wondered if Clement had taken the idea of the green planet, and the felodon, from St Clair. However, I have noticed that "[The Golden Helix](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41365)", a 1954 short story by Theodore Sturgeon, is also set on a green planet called Viridis, and involves "a scaly carnivore with [the] catlike tusks" called a felodon.

This seems beyond a coincidence. Does anyone know if these authors consciously borrowed these plot elements from each other? Were they in discussion with each other?